# Making divs wrap to the next line, regardless of their size

Tags: css, html, alignment

Right, so basically, I have a setup for an online shop which pulls all the items from a database and then prints them out as divs so they can be nicely aligned together.
My problem is, I can't figure out how to make them wrap nicely in their container : http://puu.sh/5j4Er.png

Any general tips on how this should be done ? As you can see from the screenshot, two of the divs are staying stuck to the right, probably because the left one is bigger.

The container is :

```
<div style='padding-bottom: 140px; display: block; float: left; margin-top: 20px; width: 100%;'><h2 style='margin-bottom:20px;'>$desc</h2>
```

And each div is :

```
<div style='width:".$size."px; display: block; margin-top: 10px; float: left;'>
                            <table width='".$size."px' cellspacing='10'>
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan='2'><a href='$shop?buy=$id'><h2>$item[name]</h2></a></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><a href='$shop?buy=$id'><img src='$item[img]' style='width:64px;height:64px;-webkit-box-shadow:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.496094) 3px 3px 3px;border-bottom-color:#333366;border-bottom-width:2px;border-color:initial;border-left-color:#333366;border-left-width:2px;border-right-color:#333366;border-right-width:2px;border-style:initial;border-top-color:#333366;border-top-width:2px;box-shadow:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.496094) 3px 3px 3px;padding-bottom:1px;padding-left:1px;padding-right:1px;padding-top:1px;' /></a></td>
                                    <td><a href='$shop?buy=$id'><h3><b>Prix:</b> $item[price]</h3></a>$item[description]</td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>
```

Any tips ? :)

Thanks !
Mark

Comment: Avoid inline styles. Your code is hard to read.

Comment: You **need** to start to use .css stylesheets.

Answer (score 0):

Figure out the width of your container.
Multiple the width of your div by 3. 
Subtract that from the width of your container. 
Divide that by 2.

This is the padding to the right of the first and second column. Then use the css nth-child() selector to remove the padding from all child divs with multiple of 3 to get rid of the padding from the 3rd columns so they don't float to the next line.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely cause of the behavior is that the first div container ("Citoyennete sur Aerium") has a height greater than the following div container ("Adoptez une chauve-souris").

As a result, the 4th div container is placed to the right edge of the 1st container.

To demonstrate this, add a border/outline to the div container to see the edges.

You need to make all the div containers to be the same height to avoid this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Switch your `div`, not the container, from `float:left` to `display:inline-block`.

http://jsfiddle.net/TreeTree/EK2H8/

```
div {
    width:200px;
    background:orange;
    display:inline-block;
    /*float:left;*/
    margin-right:10px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

If you uncomment the `float` line you should be able to reproduce the issue that you're seeing. `inline-block` will always go from left to right below the tallest element of the previous line.